# How do I change the path of files in the included header file dynamically?

Tags: php, include, directory, hyperlink, root

Ok this question might be kind of confusing but here goes:

How do I change the path of files in the included header file dynamically? For example I have a file in my root directory which uses the same header template as a file inside a subdirectory called articles.

Homepage:

```
/index.php
```

Articles Page

```
articles/index.php
```

Both of these files use the same header and footer included files which is under:

```
templates/header.php
templates/footer.php
```

The header file and the footer files have the paths for CSS, JS all relative to the root. How can I make it so the file paths for the CSS, JS and other links change dynamically depending on which directory the header and footer files are being included in.

This is my first question I have anywhere, so please go easy and bear with my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable when you include in your header and footer files. 
For example.. if you had

```
include 'main_menu.php';
```

Change it to

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'main_menu.php';
```

(you will have to adjust it to fit you needs)

**Edit:**
Sorry I misunderstood. Use [HTML base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) e.g.:

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/">
```

in the head section of all pages in your site.

Comment: So is this also going to change all the links inside of the "mail_menu.php" in your example? If not, this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: No it won't. You can use html `<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/">` in your `<head>` section and then all HTML includes of CSS and JS, and relative links will be relative to your site's root no matter in which directory the file that is being executed.

Comment: But what if I change domain and what if I'm hosting is locally. I know I can just type localhost but is there another way?

Comment: Usually what you will do is create a helper file. for example: templates/headInclude.php which will contain some <head> statements that you would like to have in all your pages (including the <base>, load of main CSS etc..), then you make sure to include this file in the <head> section of all your pages. When you have to change the <base> just update templates/headInclude.php and it will affect all the pages that include it.